# Bridge text effect using Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to achieve Bridge Text Effect by using Fabric.js to display text on CANVAS. 
I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726778/create-valley-text-text-with-curve-in-fabric-js) link. [image]

In that reference the Valley text has done. I am trying for Bridge text effect.
Please help me, suggestions & references also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice solution in this question using basic canvas api:

[How to make rooftext effect and valley text effect in HTML5 (or Fabric.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544735/how-to-make-rooftext-effect-and-valley-text-effect-in-html5-or-fabric-js)

I find it's diffcult to use Fabric.js to recreate it since it seems [Fabric.image did not implement](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/shapes/image.class.js) `context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height)` but only `context.drawImage(img,x,y,width,height);`

I could be wrong as I just take a first quick look of this library 15 minutes ago, have look at the solution any way, hope it helps.